# JavaFx Korean Language input

Tags: javafx, textfield

Is there a way to delete the korean character in the Text field without highlighting it first with the first delete button? Currently when I input a korean character in the textfield then press delete, it only highlights the character.

Comment: This looks like a bug in FX. What platform are you using? What version of FX?

Comment: im currently using Java in Eclipse. JavaFX version 2.0. Plus, the cursor is in the left of the character after typing the character.